# Can't use Jquery to add class to HTML when on mobile

Tags: jquery

I was just learning Jquery and I wanted to make a simple website that would be responsive by adding a class to HTML I tried 2 methods as follow:

HTML CODE:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resposive</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hello" style="font-size: 2em; width: 100%; height: 100% color: black;">
      hello
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Attempt 1:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() <= 700){
    $(".html").addClass("mobile");
  }
  else {
    $(".html").removeClass("mobile");
  }
});
```

Attemp 2:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches){
  document.getElementbyClassName("html").className += "active"
}
else{
  document.getElementbyClassName("html").className -= "active"
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
$(function(){
  var isMobile = false;
  if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
  || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) {
    isMobile = true;
  }
  if(isMobile == true){
    $(".html").addClass("mobile");
  }
});
```

I was not successful in any one of them. Can you guys please explain me how to do it? I would also like if you guys can tell me how to load 2 different HTML files based on devices like:
mobile.html=>mobile devices
computer.html=>Desktop/laptop

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to make it responsive using jquery? why not css alone? Also the first attempt will work, but not on resize. So if you window is less that 700 when the page load it will/should add the class mobile,

Comment: Your first and second method are working well. I just checked it out. The third method was not tested. Class `mobile` is added if the screen is less than the specified value. The question is different ... perhaps you want to **dynamically** add / remove a class when resizing a window in realtime?

Comment: I want to use Jquery as I am learning it. I already know how to do that with CSS

Comment: I have check all the attempts. none of them add .mobile to html

Comment: @PrayagPrajapati, Your code works. See screenshot - https://ibb.co/fHMN5J3. The class you need appeared there.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov can you tell me how to load different HTML file for desktop and phone

Comment: @PrayagPrajapati, To do this, you can use `window.location` inside a condition that checks the width of the screen.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Posted the answer. Thanks for telling me that my code worked though, or else I would have just googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it won't work when in a separate file which is wierd.
Copy the following code to your html file if you want to use it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function(){
        if (window.screen.width <= 700) {
            $("html").addClass("mobile");
        } else {
            $("html").removeClass("mobile");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note: No class is required in HTML for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code for adding and removing the class in mobile view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  myFunction();

  $(window).resize(function () {
    myFunction();
  });

  function myFunction() {
    if (window.screen.width <= 700) {
      $(".html").addClass("mobile");
    } else {
      $(".html").removeClass("mobile");
    }
  }
});
```